# Grails executor - can't use OauthService asynchronously

Tags: grails, oauth, executorservice

I installed the grails executor plugin so I can run some background task that takes a while to execute. The task requires that I call LinkedIn APIs using OauthService. The problem is that I can't seem to be able to call OauthService.accessResource in the asynchronous block, while the exact same code executes fine otherwise. Here's the code, simplified to illustrate the problem :

```
import org.grails.plugins.oauth.OauthService

class DemoController {
    OauthService oauthService

    def demo() {
     runAsync {
      println "ASYNC BEGIN"
      def baseURL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=blah"
      def async_response = oauthService.accessResource( baseURL, 'linkedin', [key:session.oauthToken.key, secret:session.oauthToken.secret], 'GET')
      println "ASYNC END"
     }
      println "SYNC BEGIN"
      def baseURL = "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=blah"
      def sync_response = oauthService.accessResource( baseURL, 'linkedin', [key:session.oauthToken.key, secret:session.oauthToken.secret], 'GET')
      println "SYNC END"
    }
}
```

Here's the output :

```
SYNC BEGIN
2012-01-12 14:55:07,163 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-10] DEBUG oauth.OauthService  - Attempting to access protected resource
2012-01-12 14:55:07,163 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-10] DEBUG oauth.OauthService  - Executing GET to http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people-search?keywords=blah
ASYNC BEGIN
2012-01-12 14:55:07,780 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-10] DEBUG oauth.OauthService  - Reading response body
2012-01-12 14:55:07,781 ["http-bio-8080"-exec-10] DEBUG oauth.OauthService  - Response body read successfully
SYNC END
```

The asynchronous process just seems to stall on oauthService.accessResource and nothing gets executed after that. I get no other output ...

Any ideas ?

Thanks for your help.

(BTW I'm using grails 2.0, groovy 1.8.5)